# OpenSL ES decode 24bit FLAC

Tags: android, android-ndk, decode, opensl

I am trying to decode a FLAC file with 24bit sample format using OpenSL ES on Android. Originally, I had my `SLDataFormat_PCM` for the `SLDataSink` setup like this.

```
_pcm.formatType = SL_DATAFORMAT_PCM;
_pcm.numChannels = 2;
_pcm.samplesPerSec = SL_SAMPLINGRATE_44_1;
_pcm.bitsPerSample = SL_PCMSAMPLEFORMAT_FIXED_16;
_pcm.containerSize = SL_PCMSAMPLEFORMAT_FIXED_16;
_pcm.channelMask = SL_SPEAKER_FRONT_LEFT | SL_SPEAKER_FRONT_RIGHT;
_pcm.endianness = SL_BYTEORDER_LITTLEENDIAN;
```

This is working well for basically any data format. Luckily the `samplesPerSec` is not respected (I don't want resampling).

Now I want to support the full bit-depth of a FLAC file with 24bit samples. When using this format, it apparently performs a bit-depth conversion, because once I load the file, and then check the `ANDROID_KEY_PCMFORMAT_BITSPERSAMPLE` info, it is 16.

When I put `bitsPerSample = SL_PCMSAMPLEFORMAT_FIXED_24;` or `SL_PCMSAMPLEFORMAT_FIXED_32`, then OpenSL ES rejects it

```
E/libOpenSLES(22706): pAudioSnk: bitsPerSample=32
W/libOpenSLES(22706): Leaving Engine::CreateAudioPlayer (SL_RESULT_CONTENT_UNSUPPORTED)
```

Any idea how this is meant to work? Is Android currently restricted to 16 bit int only?
I would also accept 32bit float, but I don't suppose that will work either.

Comment: any chance you can share a code snippet for the whole decoding task? :)

Comment: This test fixture from AndroidOS is a pretty good example of how OpenSL ES decoding works in general --- https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/wilhelm/+/idea133/tests/examples/slesTestDecodeAac.cpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it only supports 8 and 16 bits

**Sources**:

- Android [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/wilhelm/+/72721a95943c68ea0d75eb5c1ff2ab7380e4dc6f/src/android/android_sles_conversions.h) (line 60)
- [Article](http://mobilepearls.com/labs/native-android-api/ndk/docs/opensles/index.html) (*PCM data format* section)